# Eclipse :: Hide .svn files in Open Resource dialog

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to hide .svn files in the Open Resource dialog (Ctrl + Shift + R) of Eclipse?

It's very annoying when you have hundreds of files...

Cheers.

Answer (score 47):

Try the following:

Project > Properties > Resource > Resource Filters > Add

Select: Exclude All, Folders, All Children (recursive)

Name Matches: .svn

OK and Apply

Comment: Very awesome -- can ignore everything in my target folder for maven.

Comment: in my eclipse, sub folders still show `.svn` , therefore, I created a regular expression which removed .svn anywhere. This is the regex used `^(.)+[.]svn$`

Comment: This also works for people using git.  Just exclude ".git" instead of ".svn"

Answer (score 4):

What if the plugin isn't doing the work for you? Like in my situation, I have subclipse installed, but it's not hidding the files! I even uninstalled-reinstalled

Nevermind, this blog post solved the issue: http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2009/4/20/Eclipse-showing-svnbase-files-in-Open-Resource-dialog

Answer (score 3):

The Subversive/Subclipse installer will do everything for you (ignore .svn as resource), plus you get SVN support...

Comment: Question is about hiding the .svn files in `Open Resource dialog`!!!.See @Doug answer

Answer (score 1):

If you can not, for some reason, install a SVN plugin [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569032#569042) by [gimpf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15529/gimpf), you can filter the list of the Open Resource dialog.

As indicated in this SO question, you have at the top-right corner of the "Open Resource" dialog box  a small blue arrow.
Click it and "Select Working Set". 
Then create a new working set as required to include only what you need.

[alt text http://giano.com.dist.unige.it/eclipseMirror/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/whatsnew/images/openresource.png](http://giano.com.dist.unige.it/eclipseMirror/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/whatsnew/images/openresource.png)

Not as practical as having a plugin do the work for you though ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Doug indirectly pointed out, you must close and reopen the project in Eclipse after installing Subversive or Subclipse.