# How to resolve "Publishing failed: Error creating zip file XXX.jar: duplicate entry: .svn/entries"

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have a modular Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. When I try to publish this project to my embedded Tomcat server, I get this error:

```
Publishing failed
Error creating zip file XXX-web.jar: duplicate entry: .svn/entries
duplicate entry: .svn/entries
Error creating zip file XXX-domain.jar: duplicate entry: .svn/entries
duplicate entry: .svn/entries
Error creating zip file XXX-services.jar: duplicate entry: .svn/entries
duplicate entry: .svn/entries
Error creating zip file XXX-repository.jar: duplicate entry: .svn/entries
duplicate entry: .svn/entries
```

It's clear there is a problem creating the JARs because of the SVN files, but how can I instruct Eclipse to ignore anything in the **.svn** directory during the creation of JARs?

Comment: Are you using a subversion plugin? I use subclipse and have never seen this problem

Comment: No, I am using an external SVN client: SmartSVN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest installing a subversion plugin such as [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).
It should automatically fix your problem. You can still use your external SVN client and it gives you a visual flag of the files you've modified in the Package Explorer and Navigator views.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your eclipse project, could you:

- check if you reproduce the problem with the latest eclipse? (3.5 Galileo)
- if yes,

  - define a new workspace in which you ignore all .svn directories (and try to publish then): see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569032/eclipse-hide-svn-files-in-open-resource-dialog/569193#569193).
  - OR: add .svn to the list of filtered resources: see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323121/eclipse-svn-ignore-bin/1401020#1401020) (and try the publication)