# How to filter resource folders in a certain subpath of the project only?

Tags: eclipse

I found the question and answer [Eclipse :: Hide .svn files in Open Resource dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569032/eclipse-hide-svn-files-in-open-resource-dialog) but don't want to filter all resources with a given name say 'work', which is too general. I only want to exclude the work folder in one specific subfolder 'sub'. I see the "File and Folder Attributes" options "Project Relative Path" and "Location", but none of them works with somethink like:

`sub/work`

Any ideas how to get the resource filter to work in a certain subpath only?

Comment: Very closely related: [Completely exclude certain directories from Eclipse CDT project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498878/completely-exclude-certain-directories-from-eclipse-cdt-project)

Comment: Also very closely related (my own Q&A I just added): [How to exclude all parts of a folder in Eclipse except for a few specific sub-folders within it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70267494/4561887)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found a solution with the settings:

- Applies to: Files and folders
- All children (recursive) activated
- File and Folder Attributes: 
  Project Relative Path matches "sub/work"

Now all subfiles and subdirectories below this are excluded.

Comment: "Applies to: Folders" works too. All children (recursive) activated is the important part...

Comment: See also my answer here for a *ton* more detail: [How to exclude all parts of a folder in Eclipse except for a few specific sub-folders within it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70267495/4561887)

Answer (score 10):

Beware trailing slashes when you want to filter out an entire folder, ie. use

```
path/to/exclude
```

not

```
path/to/exclude/
```

Comment: Yes this is true, however for this question the "All children (recursive)" option seems to be the important part. Maybe this is just naming, i.e. there ain't really a recursion. If I exclude a folder of course all children shall be excluded too. So the real question probably is "Does anythink happen if I want to exclude a folder without activating this option?"...

Comment: And not /path/to/exclude, which is the mistake I made.

Comment: I had to use `*/path/to/exclude` when I used externally located source.

Comment: I also noticed this behavior and noted it in my answer here: [How to exclude all parts of a folder in Eclipse except for a few specific sub-folders within it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70267495/4561887)